# JavaFX Reflection effect using css

Tags: java, css, javafx, effects

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628935/javafx-2-fxml-css-reflection#12629656) question from StackOverFlow , which is about JavaFX 2.2.

Now that we are on `JavaFX 8` i need a way to add `Reflection Effect` using css...

Is that possible? I can't find anything inside [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

From the code is pretty straighforward to do this , either using `FXML` or `Plain Java Code`.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the only JavaFX effects supported by CSS are drop shadow and inner shadow

Comment: According to the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect) James D is right.

Comment: @James_D  Is there any plans to be included in JavaFX 9?

Comment: @fabian Is there any plans to be included in JavaFX 9?

Comment: IDK, but `EffectConverter` still only seems to have 2 subclasses according to the javadoc: http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/css/converter/EffectConverter.html